# How to change python command to use python2 again

Tags: python, macos

I'm running a script and I get a comma error:

```
 dbconfigure -a abc -d ...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/dbconf", line 6, in <module>
    from dbconf import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dbconf/__init__.py", line 308
    except SDBResponseError, exc:
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So I think the script uses a python command but the python command on my computer points to a python3 version. How do I fix this?

Comment: If you are on windows, you can try "py -2 yourScript.py"

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: mac os is what Im' using

Comment: You can put the [shebang](https://scriptingosx.com/2017/10/on-the-shebang/) header. First line of your script should be `#! /usr/bin/env python2`

Answer (score 0):

You can put the [shebang](https://scriptingosx.com/2017/10/on-the-shebang/) header on Unix (including mac os). First line of your script should be `#! /usr/bin/env python2`