# How to restore old python

Tags: python

I want to restore my mac back to just using python2 because I think I did something wrong when installing python3.  CurrentlyI get this:

```
python -v
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py
import site # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py
import os # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc
import errno # builtin
import posix # builtin
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py
import posixpath # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/stat.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/stat.py
import stat # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/stat.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py
import genericpath # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/warnings.py
import warnings # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/linecache.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/linecache.py
import linecache # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/linecache.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/types.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/types.py
import types # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/types.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py
import UserDict # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py
import _abcoll # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/abc.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/abc.py
import abc # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/abc.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.py
import _weakrefset # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc
import _weakref # builtin
```

What did I do?

I just don't know waht the error is. Here is another issue:

```
dbconf -a lms -d wu-llm -e prod get lms_core.db_root_pwd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/dbconf", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbconf/__init__.py", line 418, in main
    args.func(get_domains(args), args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbconf/__init__.py", line 66, in get_domains
    return [get_domain(domain, args.app, env) for env in args.environments for domain in args.domains]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbconf/__init__.py", line 60, in get_domain
    parser.error("domain does not exist: %s" % name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'error'
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to change python command to use python2 again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58647194/how-to-change-python-command-to-use-python2-again). Please don't ask duplicate questions. You can [edit the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58647194/edit) if you want to add details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change python command to use python2 again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58647194/how-to-change-python-command-to-use-python2-again)

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate of the of "How to change python command to use python2 again.". Is python2 still in your system? ( check where are python executables with e.g. `find /|grep python$`) If so, this is a duplicate question. If not, you first need to install python2 again.